# Status 404 when trying access class

Tags: java, maven, api, spring-boot

I just start learn spring-boot using maven and i follow tutorial to create RESTfull web service from this link : https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ . when i run the app and try to test using postman, the result is 404 not found.

Run app :

```
java -jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

Url test in postman :

```
http://localhost:8080/greeting
```

the greeting controller is the same as in the tutorial

here is my base class :

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And here is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>           
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>             
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: So, why do you think you should have something other than a 404? Did you write some service mapped to the URL /greeting?

Comment: You're saying that you follow the tutorial, but the pom is already very different from the one in the tutorial, so what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: exactly, I forgot to change it to the beginning, thanks @JBNizet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have made changes because the pom is different from the one in the tutorial,

For example, you have missed below `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency.so cross verify all the dependencies required for the tutorial and add.

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Try to clear(delete) `.m2` repository and perform `mvn clean install` again.